# Sharekit facebook: issue after first wrong login

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, sharekit

I am using sharekit 0.2.1, and I am facing an issue after the first wrong login. The scenario is like this:

1. open sharing view and try to login with wrong credentials.
2. close the sharing view or double tap the login button.
3. open sharing view and login with real username and password, try to share something.
4. This is when bad things start to happen:
   -The white sharing view wont disappear until the little X in top right corner is pressed.
   -I am getting this posted on facebook 
   [image]
    
   instead of getting
    [image]

If the sharing window wasn't closed (ensure that step 2 is done) everything works as intended.

Can anyone help me solve these issues?

Comment: "Whant anything done right - do it yourself". I mean try not to use firdparty librarys. Especially, if you need something simple.

Comment: Same issue here! I find Sentinel's answer the best one. Even AddThis not satisfied my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, had to rebuild everything myself. And it was easier than I thought, and way more robust than sharekit.